# Unusable space problem while create swap area (installing kali linux)

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dual-boot, debian-installer

i was installing kali linux along with windows 10  my harddisk partitions are as follow
1.System Reserved-    100MB                    Primary Partition
2.Windows Installed Folder-   126GB          Primary Partition
3.for kali linux -                     105GB         Primary Partition
4.Storage for other things-  238GB            Primary Partition

now for installing kali i have to make two partition one for root and one for swap area.

when i try to divide the 105GB partition into 100GB primary partition for root, and rest for swap area..
those rest space shows as unallocated space thus can't create one more partition for swap area..

i make both logical instead of primary....but shows warning while turning boot flag on

Comment: So to clarify your issue is with installing a Linux distro? You do not know how to format partitions properly? I hate to break it to you but actually using Kali Linux is going to require knowledge in how to do things way beyond following a step by step installer that practically does everything for you. [Please read this](https://www.kali.org/download-kali-linux-revealed-book/)

Comment: Recommended reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Answer (score 2):

You are going to get alot of snarky comments as a little google searching can quickly get you a walk through on creating a dual boot system... but here are some thoughts that might be helpful:

---

Maybe it is time to rethink this direction you are going.  A solution could be to use the Linux subsystem.  This has many benefits including a much lower chance of you making the computer unbootable.

Getting the Kali on Win10 is easy enough:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/motiba/2018/03/07/setting-up-kali-linux-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

The only downside (and this is not trivial) is that many of the tools that Kali comes with need to be manually downloaded rather than just available to you built in... But I would think this is less likely to end in tears.

I think that MichaelBay is right, you might want to seriously read: 
[Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

---

If you wish to persist, this is totally doable.  Be prepared to do this a few times to get it right, and have all your files backed up first.  More importantly:  You need to slow down, and follow a walk through to the 't'.

find some simple walk throughs

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLj2yQPWZDk
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmSi5z5l8-Y
- And many others.

I suggest you watch a bunch of these until you can predict what they are going to say.  You will learn about the many variations in how this is done.  Then choose one, and follow it completely.  You are not ready to free-style, and that is OK.  Keep going, but also read (or watch) walk throughs.  You will get stuck less, less frustrated, and get more done.